# Set an ErrorMessage when Exception occurs in Model.IsValid check

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have a `web-api-2` endpoint http://mydomain/user/add which accepts a `HTTPPut` with function signature as

```
public HttpResponseMessage AddUser(User user)
```

The User Model is

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now, suppose, the end-client now passes an invalid request like this.

```
var user = {
    "UserName": "John Doe",
    "Password": "passw0rd",
    "Age": "35blah"
};
```

This will be caught in the `if(!Model.IsValid)` check I am performing. Now I get,

```
"User.Age":{
    "ErrorMessage": "",
    "Exception": {
        "Message": "Error converting value \"35blah\" to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'Price', line 1, position 69."
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set an ErrorMessage for the entity `User.Age` when an exception occurs *in a generic way* so that I can hide `to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'Price', line 1, position 69.` which will be gibberish for the end-client? I am looking for something like,

```
[ExceptionMessage("User Age is invalid.")]
public int Age { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to achieve this result or do I have to do something like

```
var errorMessages = new List < string > ();
var age = Model.User.Age;
foreach(var error in age.Errors) {
    errorMessages.Add(
        !String.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage) ? 
            error.ErrorMessage : 
            "Age is invalid");
}
```

Any pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an easy way to intercept the conversion error (coming from JSON.NET), but if you have a preference for finding and substituting these error messages in code (as you describe at the end of your question), then you could place them in your own ActionFilter and configure it globally. That way at least you don't have to manually do it in every action. See: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: thanks. this is a better way than what i was doing anyway.